# Howto symlink Python to Python2.7 as non-superuser

Tags: python

I am a non-superuser of a linux machine. 
Currently it has 2 versions of Python.

When I invoke standard `python` command it gave version 2.6

```
$ python
[neversaint@mach71 ~]$ python
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71600, Jan 28 2011, 13:47:39) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 

$ which python
/opt/somedir/bin/python
```

It's only when I invoke with `python2.7` it gives the version 2.7

```
[neversaint@mach71 ~]$ python2.7
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 11 2013, 13:13:15) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

$ which phython2.7
/usr/bin/python2.7
```

My question is how can I set it such that whenever I call `$ python` it will give me version 2.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simlink it into some directory both accessible to your user and in your `$PATH`. For example if `/home/<your-username>/local/bin` is in your `$PATH` then you can do

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/<your-username>/local/bin/python
```

In this example `/home/<your-username>/local/bin` should be in your path before `/usr/bin`. If there is no such entry in your `$PATH` you can add it there:

```
export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH
```

You can also add this line to `.bashrc` or similar to activate it on shell start.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [shell alias](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html), `alias python=/usr/bin/python2.7` and then python will execute the result of that alias.

Answer (score 1):

in `/usr/bin` create symlink to python27 or whatever python version you have

`sudo ln -s python2.7 python`

Comment: Wouldn’t this require root/sudo privilege?

Comment: good point. yes, requires root/sudo privileges

Comment: So are you going to modify your answer, or going to leave it as what you acknowledge is a not-answer to the question where the OP wanted to know if/how to do this as non-root?

Comment: the non-root user must be sudoer to create symlinks in that folder